# How to show and hide the div when a perticular checkbox is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having multiple check boxes having their own related div with when one checkbox is clicked it shows its related div and with unchecked hides it....problem is when I click the other checkbox it hides other previous checkboxes div's.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("icon");
function hide(event) {
  if (event.checked) {
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
      x.style.display = "none";
     } else {
     x.style.display = "block";
       }
   } else {
 if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
 } else {
       x.style.display = "block";
   }
     }
  }
```

```html
 
<html>
   <body>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" onchange="hide(this)" id="extra" value="something"/>something
      <div id="icon"><a href="#"><i id="subs" class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></a><br>
          <input type="text" id="noOfRoom" value="0" /><br>
          <a href="#"><i id="adds" class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></a>
 </div>
    </label>
   <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" onchange="hide(this)" id="extra" value="something1"/>something1
    <div id="icon"><a href="#"><i id="subs" class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></a><br>
            <input type="text" id="noOfRoom" value="0" /><br>
      <a href="#"><i id="adds" class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></a>
     </div>
   </label>
   <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" onchange="hide(this)" id="extra" value="something2"/>something2
   <div id="icon"><a href="#"><i id="subs" class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></a><br>
         <input type="text" id="noOfRoom" value="0" /><br>
       <a href="#"><i id="adds" class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></a>
    </div>
    </label>
  </body>
 </html>
```

I tried to make separate function for each but if there are 50 checkboxes like this then the code is too long. then how I solve my problem.

don't know if this is basic but  just new to programming.

Thank you.

Comment: id of an element should be unique. Try giving an unique id for div elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please provide **unique id** for each element in your `HTML DOM`. If you want to maintain singularity, you can provide `class` instead of `id`. I've provided jquery solution. Check the below snippet and let know for any queries.

```js
$('.extra').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) //if it is checked
    $(this).closest('label').find('.icon').show(); //show the div with class icon
  else
    $(this).closest('label').find('.icon').hide(); //hide the div
});
```

```css
.icon {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="extra" class="extra" value="something"/>something
   <div class="icon"><a href="#"><i id="subs" class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></a><br>
      <input type="text" id="noOfRoom" value="0" /><br>
      <a href="#"><i id="adds" class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></a>
   </div>
</label>
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="extra1" class="extra" value="something1"/>something1
   <div class="icon"><a href="#"><i id="subs1" class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></a><br>
      <input type="text" id="noOfRoom" value="0" /><br>
      <a href="#"><i id="adds1" class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></a>
   </div>
</label>
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="extra2" class="extra" value="something2"/>something2
   <div class="icon"><a href="#"><i id="subs2" class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></a><br>
      <input type="text" id="noOfRoom" value="0" /><br>
      <a href="#"><i id="adds2" class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></a>
   </div>
</label>
```

You can also update the above `jquery` to simpler version.

```
$('.extra').on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest('label').find('.icon').toggle($(this).prop('checked')); 
});
```